# Can I use .NET 4.0 API calls on .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

If I make .NET 4.0 API calls and the customer only has .NET 2.0 installed, will my EXE work? I assume no -- absolutely not. But I want to reconfirm and point this out to my client yes/no.

Background... I'm from the Linux/PHP world. My client uses a Windows C# app on the frontend, and Linux/PHP on the backend. He's asked me to investigate this issue.

Comment: As far as I have seen it ends up with an error message at startup.....

Comment: What kind of "API calls" are you referring to?

Comment: Scott - things like reading/writing the registry, showing GUI elements like progressbars, tabs, dialogs, etc.

Comment: (While it was possible to access .NET3.5 API from the CLR2 runtime, as it was the same, .NET4 uses a new runtime which is "compartmentalized" from the earlier CLR. But if only .NET2 is installed, there is no .NET4 API available to even call, other issues aside.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application code targeted against the .NET 4.0 framework will not run in an environment that only has the .NET 2.0 framework installed.

See "Version Compatibility" section here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8477k21c.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The .NET 2.0 runtime will error out on you when trying to run anything written and compiled with .NET 4.0, the reverse is not true.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed. I'll share with the client. I'll wait two days and then pick the best answer. This looks to be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have your .NET 2 code access the .NET 4 libraries via a web service. If you were to expose the .NET 4 API via a web service, it would be agnostic of the .NET version and the technology between them all together.